# How i can fetch the rows using this hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate to fetch rows from the table.

```
List<Work> W= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("Select * from T_WORK ").addEntity(Work.class).list();
```

This query works fine.

But the below query is not working fine.

```
List<Work> W= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("Select * from T_WORK WHERE STATUS = 5 ").addEntity(Work.class).list();
```

I am getting a error as .

```
could not execute query

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3711)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2763)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getTimestamp(OracleResultSet.java:512)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:300)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:300)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
```

I am using Oracle and status column is of the number datatype.

In the workitem class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_CODE", nullable = false)  
private Status status;
```

Where am i wrong?
Thanks in advance.

How i can achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: You must have more in your stacktrace than simply 'could not execute query'? I'm assuming there is a problem with the column STATUS. Are you sure it exists? What is its exact datatype?

Comment: The column name is `STATUS`? Or `STATUS_CODE`? Also it seems that your column is a join. Aren't you missing it?

Comment: status_code I have just wrote the query and change the names to hide the filenames and tablenames

Comment: Can you post the schema of that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using native `SQL` query. That means, you should use **SQL** names of your fields. So use `STATUS_CODE` instead of `STATUS`.

i.e. `...createSQLQuery("Select * from T_WORK WHERE STATUS_CODE = 5 ")...`

Answer (score 0):

You are using sql not hql... So you should use  your query parameter names as same as in your db table not pojo class variable name ...